# Is it worthy upgrading to 12.10 from 12.04 for a web developer?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

In the interest of most **web developers**, who wish to upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04

But for most, the preventing factors are like -

- 12.10 is not an LTE release.

Need clarifications here -
what support and benefits exactly do canonical provide for web developer community as an LTE release? Is it worthy considering LTE or going for an upgrade.

- There are enough stories of users breaking their system after the upgrade to 12.10.

Why are the upgrades not seamless?
 It should work without breaking the system, like one click upgrades, and not re-installs  every 6months.

Thanks,

a web developer who loves ubuntu12+.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 as my main OS @ work and I don't have plans to upgrade. I also do web development. IMO it's a matter of choice in the end. My reason is simple - I don't need to upgrade. Everything I need for development currently works on 12.04 and bumping up to 12.10 is not a need. Plus, like what you mentioned, I can't afford to break stuff just to get the bleeding edge versions of apps, etc. That will only delay work.

Comment: @Marky but 12.10 is a perfect webOS, its completes 12.04 with tight integration with web-services. The concept of HUD to search inside webapps is revolutionary. Worth mentioning, webapps are now like native apps now, like we can keep open Gmail as a separate app and search inside that app.
I'm blown away with all the features, and its worth adopting the change. But, they could have made 12.10 as LTE too.

Comment: I can already do that with Fogger. The integration may not be the same, but it runs each website like a separate app. I do this with Grooveshark and a number of webapps we make, just to give an example.  The integration (webapps) I'm not very fond of because it kept on failing. At least this is my experience with 12.04. Then the Launcher integration is not too complete (not much options except for quit) that it's just wasting space. I do like the concept, but it needs further improvement.

BTW, the tight integration, web + OS, doesn't help me with work. We do stuff for private companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support means that canonical will still be providing security updates to the software, that means that packages such as apache2, php, and every package you have installed will still be receiving security updates. Note that security updates means fixes and paches for software malfunction, but it will not update a package to a new version, for example, if a new version of apache comes out, you will not get that installed unless you upgrade your ubuntu version.

This is actually good for servers, because if for example you make a web app that works great with a certain version of php, and a certain version of apache and mysql, you dont want those to be upgraded at anytime and possibly break something and give you a hard time trying to find the problem. But that doesnt meen that you will not get security updates for a long time (if you dont update) because if you use a LTS version, you will still be getting those security updates for 5 years without the need of updating.

From what i can say of the other side of the coin is that the upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 is NORMALLY seamless (except if for example, some of your apps are not compatible with new versions of software as mentioned above). It appears it's not because here in askubuntu and most forums you will only hear the bad stories of people whose upgrade went bad and they'r seeking for help, because people who succeed normally dont make threads saying they succeed.

So to conclude, i'd recommend to stick with LTS version if your computer is a dedicated server which cannot afford to go down a few hours. If that server is also a desktop computer which you use for other desktop apps and you turn it off once in a while, and you always want to have the most newest possible versions of software, you might be good updating.

Comment: Excellent detailed answer, you've convinced me too much. But I can only up vote you once. :P

To Sum up - 

If its a server setup running 12.04 - continue using 12.04. 
As you get updates by Canonical under LTS (its not upgrades!)

and for Desktop Users(i.e is not a ServerBox) then upgrade for 12.10

Thanks